# Possible to create a lookup field on custom object that points to scheduled jobs table?

Tags: lookup, salesforce-id, scheduled-job, lookup-field

Wondering if this is possible since I couldn't find anything online.

This would make it easier to click and see history for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Schedule Job Apex lookup may not be possible but however, List views can be created for jobs based on filters and an lwc can be implemented by retrieving using [ui-list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-ui-list-api/documentation)

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi, MRU } from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import ASYNC_APEX_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/AsyncApexJob';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getListUi, { objectApiName: ASYNC_APEX_OBJECT })
    listUiMethod({data,error}) { 
      //Filter out the records based on various conditons
     };
}
```

The list can then be display as a [datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example)